# TypeError: Overriding function changes state mutability from "view" to "nonpayable"

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

I have 2 issues.

1. None of my constructor values are set when the contract is deployed. All functions that call for `name`, `symbol`, `decimals`, and `totalSupply`.

2a. The functions `name()`, `symbol()`, `decimals()`, `totalSupply()` and `balanceOf()` are all flagged for *TypeError: Overriding function changes state mutability from "view" to "nonpayable".*

2b. If I add `view`, which I shouldn't besides `balanceOf`, I'm flagged for using `view` on everything besides `balanceOf`.
`typeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

abstract contract ERC20{
    function name() external virtual view returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external virtual view returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external virtual view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external virtual view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external virtual view returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external virtual returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external virtual returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external virtual returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external virtual view returns (uint256 remaining);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);


    }

    contract Ownership{

        address public contractOwner;
        address public newContractOwner;

        constructor(){
            contractOwner = msg.sender;
        }

        function changeOwnership(address _newContractOwner) external returns(bool success){
            require(msg.sender == contractOwner, "Not contract owner");
            _newContractOwner = newContractOwner;
            return success;
        }

        function approveOwnershipChange() external returns(bool success){
            require(msg.sender == newContractOwner, "Not the new contract owner");
            newContractOwner = contractOwner;
            return success;
        }
    }


    contract FullContact is ERC20, Ownership{

        constructor(string memory name_, 
                    string memory symbol_,
                    uint8 decimals_,
                    uint256 totalSupply_ ){
        }

        string public _name;
        string _symbol;

        uint8 _decimals;
        uint256 _totalSupply;

        mapping(address => uint256) _balance;
        mapping(address => mapping( address => uint256)) _allowance; 
        mapping(address => uint256) minter;


        function name() external override returns (string memory){
            _name = "Fog Of War";
            return _name;
        }

        function symbol() external override returns (string memory){
            _symbol = "FOW";
            return _symbol;

        }
        function decimals() external override returns (uint8){
            _decimals = 18;
            return _decimals;
        }

        function totalSupply() external override returns (uint256){
            _totalSupply = 100000000;
            return _totalSupply;
        } 

        function balanceOf(address _owner) external override view returns (uint256 balance){
            return _balance[_owner];
        }

        function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool success){
            require(_balance[msg.sender] >= _value, "Insufficent Funds");
            _balance[msg.sender] -= _value;
            _balance[_to] += _value;
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return success;
        }

        function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool success){
            uint256 approvedAmount = _allowance[_from][_to];
            require(approvedAmount <= _value, "Insufficent allowance");
            _balance[_from] -= _value;
            _balance[_to] += _value;
            emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return success;
        }

        function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool success){
            require(_balance[msg.sender] >= _value, "Insufficent Funds");
            _allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
            emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
            return success;

        }
        function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external override view returns (uint256 remaining){
            return _allowance[_owner][_spender];
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use "view" in the abstract contract you have defined at the top. The template you are using is for the interfaces. Interfaces provide overriding with "view" funcitonality, but not the abstract contract. Because now what you are doing is trying to set a value to a string inside a view function, which is not permitted.

I will suggest you to either change your abstract contract to an interface, or use a standized ERC20 contract.

Comment: Thank you. 

I was just trying to learn to write an ERC20 from scratch to understand all the inner workings. I made adjustments and i worked now. 

But yes I intended to use Openzep when creating a real token now that I fully understand how to construct one and what really goes on inside of the contract.